# tptp/profiling of web-application within eclipse - no data collectors available

Tags: web-applications, profiling, eclipse-tptp

I have a problem with tptp/profiling within eclipse.

Because at first I had some very strange problems, I downloaded the “TPTP all-in-one package”
(tptp.runtime.allInOne.win32.win32.x86-TPTP-4.6.2.zip) and added the stuff I need 
(Jboss-Tools, etc.)

I am using Windows XP SP3, Java 6u20, Eclipse 3.5.2.(, jboss-4.2.3.GA-jdk6)

In "Profile Configurations"/Tab "Monitor" I got
“IWAT0435E An error occurred when connecting to the host”

and in the “Profile on Server” Window in the tab Monitor I got only “pre-JRE 1.5“ as choice.

After disabling an enabling the IAC in “Preferences”/”Agent Controller” that IWAT...-problem was gone but now I don't get anything in the “Profile on Server”/”Monitor” tab, but it says  “[Monitor] The launch requires at least one data collector to be selected.”

After a (clean) restart of eclipse I now get new errors. If I try to launch and profile a normal application I get 
"Agent Controller is unavailable under port 10002.  Make sure that the service is started and the port number is correct under preferences. "
and 
“Profile on Server” leads to "Connection failed on 0.0.0.0" althoug netstat tells me that something is listening on 0.0.0.0:10002 and the Agent Controller local port is set to 10002.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Two avenues to check:

- "[hard reset](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tptp/msg07218.html)" (install TPTP on a fresh Eclipse installation, with a fresh workspace), and see if the issue persist
- "[Integrated Agent Controller](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tptp/msg07216.html)": check [how the IAC is configured](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.tptp.platform.agentcontroller.doc.user/concepts/ac/ciacintro.html).

Comment: I tried it with a fresh eclipse + workspace. And I tried it with a very simple class.

I was able to profile that class in the new WS and also in my normal one.

But in both WSs I have the problem that when I try to profile on server the window where I can choose the data collectors is empty (after some “pending...”). Not so with that simple class.

I tried to profile a complex normal java app which starts an integrated Tomcat. The process starts but nothing really happens. Not even after 30 minutes.

I have a serviceconfig.xml at the correct place and the ACServer.exe process is running.